# Delegate socket input/output streams to different threads

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, service, chat

I'm writing a chat client Android application which needs to initiate a socket connection.

Currently, I have an AsyncTask which initiates the connection, sends a login request, parses the reply and disconnects.

The issue is, I need maintain the connection indefinitely (as long as the user is using the application) and across multiple activities.

The solution I came up with thus far is to create a bound service which handles the socket connection and creates the independent threads (using an handler?) for the input and output streams.

Just two things I need know:

1. Is this a correct solution, or is a service is an overkill? (note that in the future I might need to handle notifications when the app is not in the foreground)
2. If so, how do I send the different IO threads/tasks the corresponding streams I.E. pass the streams I get from a socket to different threads?

Comment: I really need an answer to this also.